# Is this the correct way to access the objects

Tags: java, jcombobox

I'm trying to get back a list of objects from a JCombo box

It was suggested

```
private JComboBox<Object> levelComboBox;

levelComboBox = new JComboBox<Object>(logLevel);
levelComboBox.setEnabled(false);
```

But I'm confused
Is this an array list of objects or a reference to really a reference to the Object class though?
thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all, what is supposed to be an 'array list of objects', and what does it have to do with the `JComboBox`?

Comment: Apologies - i don't understand what this reference here means JComboBox<Object> . that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JComboBox<Object>` is a [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) which can be filled with `Object`s. The `<Object>` part is called a [Generic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming), about which there is a [tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 0):

Look at generics on the Oracle website, that will explain it.